# Error al guardar un libro Excel Vba ( Usando One-Drive )

Tags: excel, vba

Desde hace unos días nos han puesto la nube de OneDrive como copia de seguridad.
El problema es que ahora cuando intento guardar desde una macro un libro de excel dentro de esa Ruta me salta un error. Esta misma macro la he venido usando perfectamente desde hace años.
Realmente este es el código que uso.

```
Dim Ruta
Dim nombreLibrodestino
Ruta = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"

nombreLibrodestino = " VPed Modificados " & "Delg_" & Delegacion & " " & Day(Date) & "_" & Month(Date) & "_" & Hour(Time) & "_" & Minute(Time)
wbDestino.Activate

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Ruta & "/" & nombreLibrodestino & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, Local:=True
wbDestino.Close
```

Si quito la parte de Ruta en el Filename, lo graba bien pero en la raiz c:\

La verdad, no sabría por donde empezar a mirar, pero está claro que algo en la Ruta está fallando desde que Tengo One Drive.

El tema, es que si hago una interrupción en Ruta , la ruta que está tomando está perfecta por lo que sigo sin entenderlo.

A ver si me podéis dar alguna idea.
Gracas,

Comment: No especificas qué error da. Por otro lado, deberías probar a activar el grabador de macros y entonces grabar manualmente el libro en OneDrive. De esa manera, puedes modificar el código luego y ves bien la ruta.

Comment: No indicas el error que te da pero te comparto alguna experiencia parecida que he tenido también con Onedrive. En alguna ocasión al cambiar la contraseña de la cuenta he tenido que cerrar sesión en Onedrive y volver a logarme. En otra ocasión he tenido que pausar la sincronización, modificar el fichero excel y volver a reanudar la sincronización. No son errores recurrentes, al menos en mi caso, pero si que me han dado algún dolor de cabeza cuando no tienes ni idea de por qué ocurre...

Comment: Las preguntas deben incluir el mensaje de error completo ;)  Recuerda que puedes [edit] y añadir todo lo que veas que hace falta para que te respondan rápido

Answer (score 0):

El problema radica que vba no entiende direcciones de la nubeque empiezan por https://nombreempresa-my.sharepoint..../Documents/ y fracasa al intentar grabar el fichero, ya que detecta errores en el nombre.

De hecho el primer paso sería sustituir los `/` por `\` .
El segundo sustituir `https://nombreempresa-my.sharepoint..../Documents/` por `C:\Users\scfar\OneDrive - nombreempresa\`, pero el problema radica en que en cada ordenador estos textos son diferentes, por lo que la macro sería a medida para el ordenador en que la hagas.

Answer (score 0):

Hace un tiempo estaba con el mismo problema y la mejor solución fue ocupar

```
Ruta = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
```

Tienes que compartir el libro a los usuarios, eso sí, y otra cosa: al abrir un libro Excel lo toma como lectura.